# Handling Continuous AFNetworking API Calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, afnetworking

This problem, when i swipe screen API Calls are to be made, separate calls for separate swipe i.e. Left, Right, Top, Bottom. Also there has to be Stop API which has to be sent in 1 minute delay of swipe.

Example Camera moving on swipe for 1 second and stops: 
Swipe Left -> Left() GET API is called with AFNetworking -> (So Camera starts moving to left) -> Soon after Left API is triggered -> 1 second delay -> Stop GET API is called with AFNetworking. Repeats same method for Right(), Top(), Bottom()

I am not able to achieve this smoothly, I use this logic.

```
- (void)didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe{

if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {

    [self performSelector:@selector(moveRight) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stop:) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
} else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(moveLeft) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stop:) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
} else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(moveDown) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stop:) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
} else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(moveUp) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stop:) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
}
}
```

This are Method calls

```
-(void) moveRight
{
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:@"MoveRight" forKey:@"direction"];
[self changeDirection:parameters];
}

-(void) moveLeft
{
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:@"MoveLeft" forKey:@"direction"];
[self changeDirection:parameters];
}

-(void) moveUp
{
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:@"MoveUp" forKey:@"direction"];
[self changeDirection:parameters];
}

-(void) moveDown
{
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:@"MoveDown" forKey:@"direction"];
[self changeDirection:parameters];
}
 -(void) stop
{
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[parameters setValue:@"Stop" forKey:@"direction"];
[self changeDirection:parameters];
}
```

Now ChangeDirection Method

```
-(void) changeDirection:(NSDictionary *) parameters
{
 dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
[RestHandler afnetworkingGetApiCall():parameters :^(id response, NSString *respMsg)
 {

 }];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
});
}
```

Hope I am able to explain my question. Let me know if its not clear

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i think, you have to create model for each response. then for each call you have to create common operation queue.

Comment: This answer is no where applicable to my question, as i am already in that screen and swiping, its like live screen view of camera.